# Problem generating keys with ssh-keygen

Tags: 16.04, ssh

Can anyone tell me the problem with ssh-keygen? I already have already have created the directory, ssh-keygen acknowledges yet does not save keys

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jason/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/jason/.ssh
/home/jason/.ssh already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Saving key "/home/jason/.ssh" failed: Is a directory
jason@Keklord:~$
```

Answer (score 7):

At

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jason/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/jason/.ssh
/home/jason/.ssh already exists.
```

you are promted to enter a **file name**. You enter a directory name; `/home/jason/.ssh`.

Do not enter anything; the default value in the parenthesis is normally fine. If you want to save it to a custom location, this has to either be a file or a non-existing entity.

The error message `Saving key "/home/jason/.ssh" failed: Is a directory` is pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response! and the answer within! newbie at this

Comment: If it answers your question, you should mark it as accepted answer by ticking the check mark next to the post.

Comment: fyi: Qualico: Files/directories with a '.' (fullstop) as first character are hidden, so a normal `ls` or Files (the file-manager) won't show them. Add a `ls -a` to view from cli, or "view - show.hidden.files" from within Files to see them.